# Increase TEXT SIZE in SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

SQL Server Agent has a 512 characters limit on texts fields like nvarchar(max). I found this out after seeing my stored procedure is working correctly when I run it in SSMS but not working when is being run by a SQL Server job.

To fix this I know I can use SET TEXTSIZE { number } in my stored procedure to increase this number. However I don't want to add this line in each and every stored procedure that are being run by SQL Server jobs. Is there a way that I can set this value for SQL Server agent itself?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Thanks Jan, I ended up adding it to all sps.

Comment: I might be a little too late.  I hope that this helps someone.
You can set the textsize In your sql agent step before executing the store procedure. Simply add the textize. Updating stored procedures is a overkill.

e.g. 
SET TEXTSIZE 15000
EXEC dbo.yourspname param1, param2...

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Hear my plea MS.  Be kind to our eyes and allow us to increase the SQL Agent font size.

I use a sysinternals tool called ZoomIt.  Pressing [Control] + [1] takes a snapshot of the screen and zooms in to various magnifications.  It's a far cry from increasing the Agent job & steps, but works in a pinch.

Another work around is to return the job or it's steps in a query window.

```
select subsystem, step_id, step_name, command from sysjobsteps where job_id in 
(select job_id from sysjobs where name like '%Some Job with tiny screen letters%')
```