# Error Executing SQL Server Agent Job: JSON text is not properly formatted, Unexpected character '"'

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) Standard Edition, I am trying load a JSON into a SQL Server table using a SQL Server Agent Job, and get the following error:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '"' is found at position 508. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 13609).

But when I run it as T-SQL it inserts the data with out errors.

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
    @responseText nvarchar(MAX),
    @json nvarchar(MAX)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[HTTPRequest]
    @URI = N'http://flexapi.foresightgps.com/ForesightFlexAPI.ashx',
    @methodName = N'post',
    @requestBody =     N'{"method":"GetTagTempHistory","conncode":"PROVIDER","code":"USERNAME","wsuserid":"USERID" }',
    @SoapAction = 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP',
    @UserName = N'USERNAME',
    @Password = N'PASSWORD',
    @responseText = @responseText OUTPUT
--SELECT    @responseText as '@responseText';
  SELECT    @json= VALUE FROM OPENJSON(@responseText) WHERE [key]='ForesightFlexAPI';
INSERT INTO Localizado([TransactionID],[TrueTime],[Temp],[Name],[yLat],[xLong],[Speed],[Ignition],[Location])
SELECT [TransactionID],[TrueTime],[Temp],[Name],[yLat],[xLong],[Speed],[Ignition],[Location]
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'lax $.DATA')
WITH( TransactionID nvarchar(20) '$.TransactionID',
      TrueTime NVARCHAR(50) '$.TrueTime',
      Temp decimal(9,4) '$.Temp',
      Name nvarchar(50) '$.Name',
      yLat nvarchar(50) '$.yLat',
      xLong nvarchar(50) '$.xLong',
      Speed nvarchar(20) '$.Speed',
      Ignition nvarchar(20) '$.Ignition',
      Location nvarchar(500) 'lax $.Location'
      )
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual SQL that is being executed? The code you show isn't the same...

Comment: Hi DavidG the code posted is what I am executing. Change password and user info for security

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that the JSON string, returned from the API, got truncated when executed from SQL Server Agent Job, but not from SSMS. [So the unexpected character will always be something near 512.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063553/increase-text-size-in-sql-server-agent)

Similarly, it'll throw a [`XML parsing` error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35054159/4271117) if the job returns XML instead of a JSON string.

The solution is to [`SET TEXTSIZE -1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-textsize-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), in your SQL Server Agent Job, before executing your stored procedure. The command of your SQL Server Agent Job should be something like this:

```
SET TEXTSIZE -1
EXECUTE [your stored procedure]
```

If you are curious about the difference, you may insert your `@responseText` into a temp table and you'll certainly see a truncated JSON string without `SET TEXTSIZE -1` if `@responseText` has more than 512 characters.